# HTML Javascript onsubmit ignores my javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, onsubmit

I know there's a few similar questions to mine but none give me an answer. 
My stopped validating the user input and goes straight to Activation.php
It worked at the beginning but then i added my captcha if statement and it stopped. 
any ideas why itsnt working anymore ??

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html version="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
                          http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml11.xsd"
>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type=text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

<script>

function validateForm() {

    var username = document.Register.uname;
    var password = document.Register.pword;
    var email = document.Register.email;
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    var passw = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,41}$/;
    var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('captchaimg').value);
    var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);

      if (username.value == "")
    {
        alert("Username is required.");
        username.focus();
        return false;
    }

      if (password.value == "")
    {
        alert("Please enter a password.");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
        if (!passw.test(password.value))
    {
        alert("Password must consist of 8 to 41 characters, contain at least on digit and at least 1 upper case character");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
      if (email.value == "")
    {
        alert("Please enter your email address.");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
        if (!filter.test(email.value ))
    {
        alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
        if (str1 != str2)
    {
        alert("Captcha is incorrect");
        return false;
    }

    else{
    return true;
    }
}


</script>
</head>

<body>


 <form action="Activation.php" name="Register" accept-charset="UTF-8" method = 'POST'onsubmit = "return validateForm()"> 

  E-mail:       <input type="text" name="email" id = "emailid" value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>" size= "30" maxlength="30"  ><br><br>

  Username:     <input type="text" name="uname" id = "unameid" value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['uname'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['uname']); ?>"  > <label id="UserLabelId"><>  
  <br><br>

  Password:     <input type="password" maxlength="8" name="pword" id = "pwordid" value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['pword'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['pword']); ?>" size= "25" maxlength="25" ><br><br>

  Enter Captcha code below: </br>

  <img src ="captcha.php?rand=<?php echo rand();?>" id='captchaimg'><br>

  <input id="6_letters_code" id="txtInput" name="6_letters_code" type="text" value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['6_letters_code'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['6_letters_code']); ?>" placeholder="Type captcha here" ><br>

   <input type="hidden" id="txtCaptcha" /></label>

  <small>Can't read the image? click <a href='javascript: refreshCaptcha();'>here</a> to refresh</small> </br>

  <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" class="quoteButton">
  </form>


    <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>


    function refreshCaptcha(){
    var img = document.images['captchaimg'];
    img.src = img.src.substring(0,img.src.lastIndexOf("?"))+"?rand="+Math.random()*1000;
    }




    </script>

    </body>
    </html>`enter code here`
```

Comment: What happens if you add the missing space between `'POST'` and `onsubmit`: `<form action="Activation.php" name="Register" accept-charset="UTF-8" method='POST' onsubmit="return validateForm()">`?

Comment: @PaulRoub I don't think that should matter. The quote delimits the attribute, so a space isn't needed.

Comment: `captchaimg` is an image, not an input. It doesn't have `.value`.

Comment: My guess is the text associated with the captcha is supposed to go in the `txtCaptcha` hidden input. But there doesn't seem to be any code to put it there.

Comment: I thought captchaimg is just an id for "captcha.php?rand=<?php echo rand();?>" which gets the captcha value from captcha.php which is my captcha generator

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 IDs on :

```
<input id="6_letters_code" id="txtInput" name="6_letters_code" type="text" value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['6_letters_code'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['6_letters_code']); ?>" placeholder="Type captcha here" ><br>
```

I'm pretty sure XHTML 1.0 will only take the first ID associated with this element so that it will never see the txtInput ID?

Also, for STRING comparisons in JS you'll want to use !== or === for `if (str1 != str2)` it's very inconsistent whether it will work with a double == or !=.

If those don't solve your issues then let me know.

Comment: I kept both Ids by accident. I have now kept the 6_letter_code id and updated my java script: var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('6_letter_code').value); .
I've been using double equals signs before and it worked fine, i just dont know what I may have entered  maybe by accident that stopped it from working. Ive upated it however to === and problem continues :/ 
Have to keep looking , thank you for answer though

Comment: where is the removeSpaces() function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in my captcha validation part. 
Once i commented out the below it worked fine.

Thanks everyone, please let me know if you know how to validate a captcha in javascript!

```
//var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('captchaimg').value);
    //var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('6_letter_code').value);

and 
/*  if (str1 !== str2)
   {
       alert("Captcha is incorrect");
        return false;
    }*/
```